# Getting stuck in truffle testing

Tags: web3js, truffle, nodejs

I am trying to run a test and I am getting the following message;

[image]

I have tried the following;

`npm install scrypt`

`npm install web3`

as to solve the yellow message and when running `truffle test`
truffle get's stuck and no test are shown...

This is the test code;

```
var TtdmToken = artifacts.require("./TtdmToken.sol");

contract('TtdmToken', function(accounts) {

    it'sets the total supply upon deployment', function() {
    return TtdmToken.deployed().then()function(instance) {
    tokenInstance.totalSupply();
    }).then(function(totalSupply) {
        assert.equal(totalSupply.toNumber(), 100000,'sets the total supply to 1,000,000');
    });
  });
})
```

What might be causing the issue as it gets stuck with `truffle test` but other commands works but the yellow message keeps on showing...

Comment: Are you running ganache-cli concurrently?

Comment: Yes it is, and I made sure to create different workplaces to help better to track the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some syntax errors (also that test is checking the total supply, not setting it), please try the following:

```js
contract('TtdmToken', (accounts) => {
  it('Checks whether or not the total supply is equal to 1,000,000', () =>
    TtdmToken.deployed()
    .then(tokenInstance => tokenInstance.totalSupply())
    .then((totalSupply) => {
      assert.equal(
        totalSupply.toNumber(),
        1000000,
        'Total supply was not equal to 1,000,000'
      );
    })
  );
})
```

Comment: That does not explain the `truffle get's stuck and no test are shown` part though.

Comment: The first that came in mind as it is not loading the tests so I though it might be related...

Comment: Thanks for the coding suggestions, but the test still not going through, it kind of freezes until I ctrl-z. I

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because [I didn't have any networks defined in truffle-config.js](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/1976)

Once I explicitly added the `development` network, `truffle test` began to work.

```js
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*"
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```